# mysql query to join 3 tables having no association in one of the tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, database-design

[SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6d87f/5/4)

I have following tables for events.

**events**

```
+---------+---------------+
| column  |     type      |
+---------+---------------+
| id      | int(11)       |
| title   | varchar(255)  |
| content | longtext      |
+---------+---------------+
```

**event_attachment**

```
+----------+---------------------------------+
|  column  |              type               |
+----------+---------------------------------+
| id       | int(11)                         |
| caption  | varchar(255)                    |
| type     | enum('AUDIO', 'VIDEO', 'IMAGE') |
| path     | varchar(255)                    |
| position | int(11)                         |
+----------+---------------------------------+
```

**event_gallery**

```
+---------------+---------+
|    column     |  type   |
+---------------+---------+
| event_id      | int(11) |
| attachment_id | int(11) |
+---------------+---------+
```

I can get event attachments from separate query like -

```
SELECT ea.id, ea.caption, ea.type, ea.path,  ea.position
FROM `event_attachment` ea
WHERE ea.id
    IN (SELECT eg.attachment_id FROM `event_gallery` eg WHERE eg.event_id = {$event_id})
ORDER BY ea.position ASC;
```

But I can not perform `JOIN` on `event_attachment` and `events` directly.

Also I can get `event` and it's single attachment with -

```
SELECT e.title , eg.attachment_id
FROM `events` e 
JOIN `event_gallery` eg
    ON e.id = eg.event_id
GROUP BY e.id
```

I can not get these above two queries to work together and give me entire event details along with it's attachments in single query.

What I want is to get event list along with event attachment at position one for every event. Now an event may or may not attachments.

Desired output -

```
+----+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+----------+--+
| id |       title       |                        content                        |                   path                   | position |  |
+----+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+----------+--+
|  1 | Barclay Delacruz  | Soluta minim eiusmod laborum minima cumque fugiat     | e2d80cd9-7e4f-4a3d-92b5-d5c600367499.jpg |       1  |  |
|  2 | Lesley Strickland | Rem culpa dolor doloremque modi nisi esse exercita... | 2b15b00f-f094-469b-a56f-de7460326110.jpg |       1  |  |
+----+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+----------+--+
```

**NOTE** Question may sound duplicate because English is not my first language and it's difficult to put entire scenario in single question.

Comment: "I can not perform JOIN on event_attachment and events directly"  ?? Why not?

Comment: @Strawberry I am creating sqlfiddle. Will update question with the link in few moments

Comment: @Strawberry I have added sqlfiddle with sample data and queries. Please have a look.

Comment: @Strawberry please see update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic stuff!

```
SELECT e.id event_id
     , e.title
     , CASE WHEN LENGTH(e.content) > 10 THEN CONCAT(TRIM(SUBSTR(e.content,1,7)),'...') ELSE e.content END content
     , ea.id attachment_id
     , CASE WHEN LENGTH(ea.caption) > 10 THEN CONCAT(TRIM(SUBSTR(ea.caption,1,7)),'...') ELSE ea.caption END caption
     , ea.type
     , CASE WHEN LENGTH(ea.path) > 10 THEN CONCAT(TRIM(SUBSTR(ea.path,1,7)),'...') ELSE ea.path END path
  FROM events e
  JOIN event_gallery eg
    ON eg.event_id = e.id
  JOIN event_attachment ea
    ON ea.id = eg.attachment_id
 WHERE ea.position = 1;

+----------+------------------+------------+---------------+------------+-------+------------+
| event_id | title            | content    | attachment_id | caption    | type  | path       |
+----------+------------------+------------+---------------+------------+-------+------------+
|        1 | Barclay Delacruz | Soluta...  |             1 | c          | IMAGE | e2d80cd... |
|        2 | Jeremy Ballard   | Sapient... |             4 | Ipsum q... | IMAGE | 2b15b00... |
+----------+------------------+------------+---------------+------------+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Yes. That's right. It also ellipsize the caption and content which I needed but not the path as I need to show image also. Thank you.

Comment: I only did that for ease of display here. In practice, I would handle those kind of issues in the presentation layer (e.g. with a bit of PHP, if appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a `JOIN` for the tree tables. Something like that:

```
SELECT e.title, ea.attachment
FROM `event_attachment` ea
JOIN `event__gallery` ag 
ON ea.id = eg.attachment_id JOIN `event` e
ON eg.event_id = e.id
ORDER BY ea.position ASC;
```

If this is not what are you want sorry but my english is worst of your and i understood the question.

**EDIT**:

I've tested my query in your SQLFIDDLE and i think that this is what you want:

```
SELECT e.id, e.title, e.content, ea.path, ea.position
FROM `event_attachment` ea
JOIN `event_gallery` eg 
ON ea.id = eg.attachment_id JOIN `events` e
ON eg.event_id = e.id
GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY ea.position ASC ;
```

Comment: I have added sqlfiddle with sample data and queries. Please have a look.

Comment: Yes. It does. Thank you :) I also need ellipsis after certain length of characters so accepted answer does that. It's basically same but covers my use case . Thanks again

Comment: Ok:) Thanks a lot and sorry but i don't understood that you wanted ellipsis!